# Convert formula with string function into a VBA equivalent

Tags: excel, vba, string-function

I would like to turn Excel formulas with string functions into VBA equivalents.

There are several lines of formulas. I'm going to give two examples.

There is a copy a txt report in column A. Columns B thru O sort through the rows of A, picking out pieces using some of the following formulas:

```
=IF(MID(A6,60,1)="=",MID(A6,52,15),IF(MID(A6,57,1)="=",MID(A6,53,8),C1))
```

and

```
=IF(A2="","-",IF(LEFT(A2,1)="1","pg","-"))
```

Here's a snapshot of a test report.

[image: Mock Report]

I'd like to loop through the formulas and send to Sheet2 starting with A2 (due to headers) not go through the steps of copying then pasting to A1, copying columns B thru O, and then sorting out the "-".

I tried recording a macro and imputing the formulas, but I couldn't make it happen.

Comment: I think this is better of full VBA instead of using Formulas.

Comment: I agree with @PatricK that you'd be better off just re-writing the formula as a macro perhaps using `InStr`, `If` and `Select Case` functions.

Comment: if you expect there to be only 1 equal sign in "A6" then using the instr function would definitely be easier.  ie if inst(1,range("a6").value, "=") = 60 then......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub convert()
Dim ws As Worksheet, thisRng As Range
Set ws = Sheet1
Set thisRng = Sheet1.Range("B1")' Select the cell to place data into

'   Break up the formula logically first and it becomes easier to convert
'   =IF (MID(A6,60,1)="=",     MID(A6,52,15),    else if IF(MID(A6,57,1)="=",     MID(A6,53,8),        else    C1))
If Mid(ws.Range("A6").Value, 60, 1) = "=" Then
    thisRng = Mid(ws.Range("A6").Value, 52, 15)
    Else
        If (Mid(ws.Range("A6").Value, 57, 1)) = "=" Then
            thisRng = Mid(ws.Range("A6").Value, 53, 8)
        Else
            thisRng.Value = ws.Range("C1").Value
        End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks again everyone for he quick feed back!

Comment: Is that the answer?  If so please don't forget to +1 it.